# Fire event before sending email in Laravel

Tags: email, events, laravel, send

My webhost imposes a limit on how many emails can be sent from my email account. I'd like to create an event that logs how many emails have been sent that day every time a new email is sent. If the maximum number of emails is reached, I'll switch my app to a different email account to avoid conflicts.

Creating the event shouldn't be a problem. My question is how would I go about setting it up so it fires every time an email is sent? Would it be something like extending Mail::send so that it includes something like this?

```
 $event = Event::fire('mail.send', array($data));
```

Comment: Why dont you use just mailchimp or some other api? They are already preconfigured in Laravel. Seems alot easier that trying to swap mail hosts each day.

Comment: I'm considering it. I've used mailgun with other projects, but mailgun needs me to edit DNS records, which unfortunately the web host I'm using for this project doesn't allow... Maybe I'll have to get another web host...

Comment: Just use Mandrill then. You can use them for your outbound SMTP sending - and use your current web host for your inbound SMTP - that way no MX records need to be changed at all. I do this on a number of projects that involve mass mailing.